# remove a column from the row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This may be a basic question... but I am a newbie to jquery.
I need to remove the last column from a table row below

```
var ptr = $(this).closest("tr")

ptr.remove("td :last")
```

Is this the way to do it?

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the last *cell* from one row or remove the the entire column (the last cell in *all* rows)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. **If you want to remove the last cell in each row (the whole column)**

   You can do the following

   ```
   var ptr = $("#myTable").find("tr");
   ptr.find("td:last").remove();
   ```

   [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/2fvGZ/2/)
2. **If you only want to remove the last cell in the first row do this**

   ```
   var ptr = $("#myTable").find("tr:first");
   ptr.find("td:last").remove();
   ```

   [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/2fvGZ/3/)

Anyway, i dont know how your table is structured (no source in your question).
You should use `thead` and `tbody` for search engine optimization and good html.

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <td>first column</td>
           <td>second column</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>first cell first row</td>
           <td>second cell first column</td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
           <td>first cell second row</td>
           <td>second cell second column</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>        
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a column from row by **cells**.
eg: `$("#yourTableId").find('tr')[RowNo].cells[ColumnNo].remove();`

Here `RowNo` is your row position start from 0 to n.
and `ColumnNo` is your td no start from 0 to n.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: Thank you FrankerZ.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is close.  You should do this instead:

```
ptr.remove("td:last");
```

With the space, you would be essentially asking for the last of all *ancestors* of all of your tds.  Without the space, you're saying you want all tds that are last, which should give you your last td.

Comment: I think this will only remove the last cell in the first row. What he want, i think, is to remove the whole column (every last cell in each row).

Comment: @dknaack The title of the question suggests that pri_dev wants to remove a `td` (column) from a row.

Comment: @Jacob, i dont think this is clear. If he want to remove the last cell in in the first row, your right. But the answer is about removing the column. lets see what pri_dev answers to your comment.